# jQuery UI datepicker not opening to previously selected date if format doesn't include day

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have noticed an unexpected behavior in jQuery UI datepicker.

Whenever I use a format that does not include day, e.g. 'MM yy' (October 2011),
the datepicker, when shown next time, points to today instead of the previous date.

This does not occur when for format is used e.g. 'dd/mm/yy' (01/10/2011).

I think this might be in fact a bug and I will report it to the jQuery UI community.

Anyways, in the meantime, **I wonder if you faced this problem before and can suggest me a workaround**?

[Example presenting the problem can be found here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nEGTv/2/)

**EDIT:**
For completeness: I submitted this issue to jQuery UI community as a bug. [For those interested it could be found here.](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8214)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you marked as correct is not really correct. Let me break it down.

```
$("#monthDate1").focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    //add event to perform on done button click
    $(".ui-datepicker-close").click(function(){
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $("#monthDate1").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        $("#monthDate1").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    });
});
```

By doing `$("#monthDate1").focus` you are biding the `click` event each time your control goes into `focus` which is very bad.

Consider launching `$.ajax` each time you `click` on the `$(".ui-datepicker-close")`. Your function is going to request from the server not one time but as many times as your control came into `focus`.

Fix:

Do not bind `focus` on the `$("#monthDate1")` but instead use `live` or `delegate`(for the jquery versions >= 1.9.3 if i`m not mistaken).

Here is an example with `live`:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-close").live('click', function(){
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $("#monthDate1").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            $("#monthDate1").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        });
```

Here is an example with `delegate`:

```
$("#ui-datepicker-div").delegate(".ui-datepicker-close", 'click', function(){
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $("#monthDate1").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    $("#monthDate1").datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
});
```

**UPDATE**

This update comes to the response i gave in my comment.
It is not really ok to user `$(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();` inside the `focus` event because its a little buggy.

Here is how you should do it with no problems:

```
var dynamicStyle = $("<style> .ui-datepicker-calendar { display: none; } </style>")
                        .attr("id", "dynamicDatepickerStyle");
$("#monthDate1").datepicker({
    beforeShow: function ()
    {
        $("body").append(dynamicStyle);
    },

    onClose: function ()
    {
        $("#dynamicDatepickerStyle").remove();
    }
});
```

this is going to append the `style` which will `hide` the `calendar` when you `open` the `datepicker` and will `remove` the `style` when the `datepicker` is closed in order that it will not affect other datepickers on the page. This is if you want to have several datepickers on the page, some with `calendar` and some without it.

Comment: Thanks for this comments I agree as to the use of `live()` or better per 1.7+ versions of jQuery `on()` method (+1). I read that you disagree with use of focus all together. Therefore, I would much appreciate if you can provide a working example, as I am not sure how would you otherwise hide the `.ui-datepicker-calendar` which is also a must in my case.

Comment: You can still keep `$(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();` inside the `focus` handler, this is if you want only for this datepicker to not show the calendar.
Or you could globally override it, but be aware that this will affect all datepickers in your site where you load it:
`<style>
 .ui-datepicker-calendar
 {
  display:none;
 }
</style>`
Or you could just inject the style on the page you need it like this:
`$('some_container').append('<style> .ui-datepicker-calendar { display:none; } </style>');`

Answer (score 4):

I solved your issue. please Checkout this link  http://jsfiddle.net/nEGTv/3/

Just add this line to your code `$("#monthDate1").datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));` in your `$("#monthDate1").focus` function.

Comment: Thank you very much more then great full, I thought there must be a way to get it done. Good job +1 and accept :)